# Selection Sort - show each intermediate array

Tags: sorting, selection

Describe selection sort and sort the array [7, 4, 8, 2, 9 ,1] with it (increasing order), showing each intermediate array in which a new element is selected. For each intermediate array indicate which part of the array is sorted. Also indicate how many comparisons and how many variable assignments are necessary in total for each intermediate array.

My response: [7, 4, 8, 2, 9, 1]

7, 4, 8, 2, 1, 9 (1st pass)
7, 4, 1, 2, 8, 9 (2nd pass)
2, 4, 1, 7, 8, 9 (3rd pass)
2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 9 (4th pass)
1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9 (5th pass)

What I am doing is finding the largest number in the array, and throwing it to the back of the array.

Please could you tell me how where I have gone wrong, as I feel this answer is not complete.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you sorted the array ok, but you forgot about *"For each intermediate array indicate which part of the array is sorted. Also indicate how many comparisons and how many variable assignments are necessary in total for each intermediate array."*

For example, first pass:

intermediate array: [7,4,8,2,1,9]

sorted part: a[5:5] = [9]

comparisons needed: 5 (compare 4&7, 8&7, 2&8, 1&8, 8&9)

variable assignments: 4 (max := 7, max := 8, max := 9, last_position := max)

and continue for the next passes.

You didn't give a precise definition for what the number of assignments and comparisons mean, so I just used a criterion that sounded reasonable. Just be sure to use whatever your assignment actually specified - if it said something different then don't expect your answer to match mine.